# Money plant leaves are too big ~6"

Tags: houseplants, leaves, fertilizer

Why is my money plant (pothos) growing such big leaves?

https://instagram.com/p/3u2cUloqIP/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pothos plant.  It has two forms: juvenile with small leaves and mature with very large leaves. More details [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/5537/499);

When the vine is in a good situation the leaves double or triple in size and become lobed.